Traversing variable thru batchable steps
Let' say we have this class
    global class ObjectPermsBatch implements Database.Batchable<sObject>,  Database.stateful {
        Id permset;
        List<ObjectPermissions> permSets = new List<ObjectPermissions>();
        public ObjectPermsBatch(Id permSet) {
            this.permSet = permSet;
        }
        global DataBase.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext bc) {
            Id permSet = this.permset;
            DataBase.QueryLocator  ql;
            try {
                ql = Database.getQueryLocator('SELECT Id,' + 
                    'SObjectType,' + 
                    'PermissionsRead,' + 
                    'PermissionsEdit,' + 
                    'PermissionsCreate,' + 
                    'PermissionsDelete ' +
                    'FROM ObjectPermissions ' + 
                    'WHERE ParentId = :permset');
            } catch(Exception e) {
                system.debug(e.getMessage());
            }
            return ql;
        }
        global void execute(Database.BatchableContext bc, List<ObjectPermissions> records){
            system.debug('context:' + bc);
            system.debug('perm sets:' + this.permSets);
            for(ObjectPermissions op : records) {
                this.permSets.add(op);
                system.debug('execute perm:' + op);
            }}

but inside every iteration I can see an empty value for this.permSets on the early beginning. Moreover I'm sure that there are at least 1000 records when it comes to queryLocator.
What do I want - just collect all of permissions tied to particular permission set and invoke another batchable with this list

my bad - there is a need to make my List at least public

with Database.Stateful, class variables don't need to be public. As an aside, your variable names are confusing permset should be permSetId, permSets should be objectPermissions
